# is "start with the 10 minute recap" grammatical and idiomatic in a lecture?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

The lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/4IAXaixaLWE?t=80)

> we'll start with the 10 minute recap on what you've seen in the first
>   week about neural networks,  so as you know you can think of machine
>   learning, deep learning in general as modeling a function ...

the "recap" shows up for the first time at this time point.

in this context, is it grammatical and idiomatic to use "the" before "recap"?

is "a recap" more grammatical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He's actually saying:

> We'll start with **a** 10-minute recap on what you've seen in the first week

*A*, not *the*.  This is idiomatic.  *The* would be fine if he was referring to a recap he'd already mentioned.

However, I would have said:

> a 10-minute recap **of** what you've seen ...

but I don't think the idiom requires this preposition.  *On* is fine.

Comment: ...unless he's reading off an agenda, and this item is *the* recap.